# B+ tree index size given size of data

Tags: database, indexing

If I create a B+-tree index for the key table(a,b,c), in a database with 2KB pages and using 64 bit pointers, where a,b and c are all of size 4 bytes and the total size of each record is 88 bytes.

What is the range of possible values for the depth of the index if the table has 36,279 rows?

Answer (score 0):

For minimum capacity:

2 * ceiling[n/2]^(d-2) * ceiling[(n-1)/2] = 36279

solved for d gives you 3.5, so depth is 4.

For max capacity:

n^(d-1) * (n-1) = 36279

solved for d gives you 2.3 so depth is 3.

Therefore the answer is 3-4.

Oh, and n is 102.